# Is there a way to solve the combination between routes that affect each other?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have Global file which holds the following routes:

global.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginPage from "../../pages/Authentication/Login";
import SignupPage from "../../pages/Authentication/Signup";

const Global = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignupPage />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Global;
```

and another file called Admin which holds these routes:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import "../../styles/App.scss";
import { ThemeContext } from "../../context/ThemeContext";
import { DARK_THEME, LIGHT_THEME } from "../../constants/themeConstants";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import MoonIcon from '../../assets/icons/moon.svg';
import SunIcon from '../../assets/icons/sun.svg';
import BaseLayout from "../../layout/BaseLayout";
import DashboardScreen from "../../screens/Dashboard/DashboardScreen";
import PageNotFound from "../../screens/error/PageNotFound";

const Admin = () => {
  const { theme, toggleTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  console.log(theme);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (theme === DARK_THEME) {
      document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    }
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<BaseLayout />}>
          <Route path="/admin" element={<DashboardScreen />}></Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />}></Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <button
        type="button" 
        className="theme-toggle-btn"
        onClick={toggleTheme}
      >
        <img
          src={theme === LIGHT_THEME ? SunIcon: MoonIcon}
          alt=""
          className="theme-icon"
        />
      </button>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
};

export default Admin;
```

and then combined them in one file:

```
// import "./App.scss";
import { SidebarProvider } from "./context/SidebarContext";
import { ThemeProvider } from "./context/ThemeContext";

import Admin from "./routes/admin/Admin";
import Global from "./routes/global/Global";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Global />

      <ThemeProvider>
        <SidebarProvider>
          <Admin></Admin>
        </SidebarProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

what happens that is that the sidebar from the admin Router comes up with the login or sign up pages from Global component although the sidebar is from admin file in a different router as you can see in the following image:

[image]

I tried a lot of times with different ways to seperate them by playing with the routes but I couldn't. There has to be a way so that the sidebar don't come up with the the routes although the sidebar itself is a different route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two routers are rendered at the same time and so also render any matched routes at the same time.

You only need one router per React application. Refactor the code so `App` renders the single necessary `Router` component, and all routes rendered under a single `Routes` component that handles route matching. Descendent route paths are built relative to their parent route component.

Example:

Update `Admin` to be a layout route component that renders an `Outlet` for its nested routes.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Admin = () => {
  const { theme, toggleTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  console.log(theme);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (theme === DARK_THEME) {
      document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    }
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <>
      <Outlet />
      <button
        type="button" 
        className="theme-toggle-btn"
        onClick={toggleTheme}
      >
        <img
          src={theme === LIGHT_THEME ? SunIcon : MoonIcon}
          alt=""
          className="theme-icon"
        />
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignupPage />} />
          <Route
            element={(
              <ThemeProvider>
                <SidebarProvider>
                  <Admin />
                </SidebarProvider>
               </ThemeProvider>
            )}
          >
            <Route element={<BaseLayout />}>
              <Route path="/admin" element={<DashboardScreen />} />
              <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Code Splitting

You *could* create functions that return JSX

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginPage from "../../pages/Authentication/Login";
import SignupPage from "../../pages/Authentication/Signup";

const globalRoutes = () => (
  <>
    <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
    <Route path="/signup" element={<SignupPage />} />
  </>
);

export default Global;
```

```
const adminRoutes = () => (
  <Route
    element={(
      <ThemeProvider>
        <SidebarProvider>
          <Admin />
        </SidebarProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    )}
  >
    <Route element={<BaseLayout />}>
      <Route path="/admin" element={<DashboardScreen />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
);
```

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          {globalRoutes()}
          {adminRoutes()}
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It would be better to render the root-level routes directly where each routed component renders ***descendent*** routes (*Routed components that render another `Routes` component and set of routes*) instead. Basically each route is a sort of "namespace".

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginPage from "../../pages/Authentication/Login";
import SignupPage from "../../pages/Authentication/Signup";

const Global = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
      <Route path="/signup" element={<SignupPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default Global;
```

```
const Admin = () => {
  const { theme, toggleTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  console.log(theme);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (theme === DARK_THEME) {
      document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    }
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<BaseLayout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<DashboardScreen />} /> // <-- "/admin"
          <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <button
        type="button" 
        className="theme-toggle-btn"
        onClick={toggleTheme}
      >
        <img
          src={theme === LIGHT_THEME ? SunIcon: MoonIcon}
          alt=""
          className="theme-icon"
        />
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<Global />} />
          <Route
            path="/admin/*"
            element={(
              <ThemeProvider>
                <SidebarProvider>
                  <Admin />
                </SidebarProvider>
              </ThemeProvider>
            )}
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But my idea is that later I will have a lot of routes and I want to organize them

Comment: Is there a way to seperate them while not having the same problem?

Comment: @YousefAlsakkaf Not really when all you have are root-level routes. You could abstract them into a function that returns an array of routes. You could switch to rendering descendent routes instead, in which case, code splitting becomes trivial. Would you like me to update with an example?

Comment: yes please so that I can understand

Answer (score -1):

Change your Structure based on your requirements. you can create your two different layouts for different page requirement

Look at the below routes and structure. This will work for you

App.js

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        {/* ***** make login page without sidebar ***** */}
        <Route exact path='/' component={LoginPage} />
        <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignupPage} />
        <Route exact path='/admin/*' component={WithSidebarPageRoute} />
        <Route path='/not-found'>
            <PageNotFound />
        </Route>
        <Redirect from='*' to='/not-found' />
    </Switch>
</Router>;
```

WithSidebarPageRoute.js

```
<MainLayout>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard" component={DashboardPage}  />
        <Route exact path="/admin/page1" component={PageOne}  />
        <Route exact path="/admin/page2" component={PageTwo} />
        <Redirect from="*" to="/not-found" />
    </Switch>
</MainLayout>
```

MainLayout.js

```
const { children } = this.props;
return (
    <main className="cr-app bg-light">
    {/* ***** sidebar only render in admin pages ***** */}
    <Sidebar />
        <Content>
            <Header />
            {children}
        </Content>
    </main>
);
```

Let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: The code in this answer uses a different syntax because it's the older v5 API. The organization *might* be helpful, but there are simply just too many breaking changes between RRDv4/5 and v6 that routing really is a completely different.